# Conectarme a Oracle con java da java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28009

Tags: java, oracle

Llevo varias horas intentando ingresar a mi base de datos mioracle a la tabla clientes, pero no logro entrar. tengo el Driver de oracle. Sin embargo cuando lo hago con mysql está todo correcto, pero quiero hacerlo con oracle porque lo tengo de tarea personal.
**Me sale este error a la hora de conectar con oracle**
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28009: la conexión como SYS debe ser como SYSDBA o SYSOPER

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class imprimir {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Conexion a la base de datos oracle
            try {
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "sys", "321admin");
                    System.out.println("Ingresado");
                  
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           
            
    }

}

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28009: la conexión como SYS debe ser como SYSDBA o SYSOPER
```

Ahora si lo pongo así:

```
try {
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe as sysdba", "sys", "321admin");
                    System.out.println("Ingresado");
                  
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Me sale esto

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12505: No se puede conectar a la base de datos. El SID xe as sysdba no está registrado con el listener en host localhost port 1521. (CONNECTION_ID=4wuYD11uRQetUXdUzomraA==)
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-12505/
    at com.oracle.database.jdbc/oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonNetException(T4CConnection.java:1398)
    at com.oracle.database.jdbc/oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:991)
    at com.oracle.database.jdbc/oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1157)
    at com.oracle.database.jdbc/oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:104)
    at com.oracle.database.jdbc/oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:825)
    at com.oracle.database.jdbc/oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:651)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at imprimir.main(imprimir.java:15)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: ORA-12505: No se puede conectar a la base de datos. El SID xe as sysdba no está registrado con el listener en host localhost port 1521. (CONNECTION_ID=4wuYD11uRQetUXdUzomraA==)
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-12505/
```

Yo puedo conectarme normal a mi oracle y hacer consultas
[image: Consulta a la tabla clientes]

Comment: ¿Alguna de [estas preguntas](/search?q=ora-12505) te da una pista de lo que está sucediendo?

Comment: Busca en la interfaz gráfica cuál sería la cadena de conexión correcta para tu entorno, revisando en las propiedades de esa conexión que funciona.